Ubuntu Server Boot Stuck at "Mountpoint Cache Hash Table Entries"
I'm encountering an issue where my Ubuntu server installation gets stuck during boot at the "mountpoint-cache hash table entries" line. I've attempted multiple bootable USBs and other Linux distributions, but they all stop at the same point.
Here are the details:

I previously had Ubuntu installed on this hardware, and it worked perfectly a few days ago.
I decided to perform a fresh installation (same Ubuntu version, same hardware).
After selecting from the Grub menu, the installation process freezes at the same stage every time.
The issue persists across different Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.), as well as Windows—none of them can fully boot.

System Specifications:

Intel dual-core CPU
Nvidia 2GB graphics card
Samsung 500GB SSD
8GB DDR3 RAM (4GB+4GB)
The BIOS is quite old and lacks many modern configuration options.

Code where it's stuck at
[ 0.345108] landlock: Up and running.
[ 0.345151] Yama: becoming mindful. 
[ 0.345322] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[ 0.345719] Μount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, li near)
[ 0.345808] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 byte nears, linear)
_ 

This last line keeps blinking... Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, or how I can troubleshoot it further? I just want to set this up as a server again, and it was working fine before the fresh installation attempt. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!!
Thanks!!!
FOUND A SOLUTION: (Kinda)
It appears the issue was not a stuck boot but rather slow boot and startup time. After running the server for several hours (3+), the installation process finally began.
Potential Causes For Anyone Else Facing The Issue:
Older Hardware: If you are using outdated hardware, it may take significantly/or in my case awfully longer to boot and install Ubuntu/other OS.
Hardware Issues: It's also possible that there are underlying hardware problems, such as issues with the processor or motherboard (In my case I think). These can contribute to slow performance is what I found after spending two days of tests.
Recommendations:
Patience: If you are using older hardware, be prepared for longer boot and startup times. Allow the system sufficient time to complete its processes.
Kudos!

If multiple OS have issues it is a hardware problem.

welp... ram fine, ssd fine, checked the cmos, smps fine... only things left are motherboard or processor sigh... but if it's a hardware issue... why would even the bootloader start and show some data and hang up after... imma do more tests
